# terminal select statement is not working inside psql DATABASE_URL

Tags: postgresql, psql, quoted-identifier

my select * from 'Skills' is not working properly.

Please refer to pics. did not work in either tables. I do have data inside the tables.

[image: not work in select statement in terminal postgresql]

Comment: Please do **not** post code or text information as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Comment: Please also read this:  https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: Use ; to finish your SQL statement and to execute it